# external css vs server side style add

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Why does image not show up after click if style `display:none` set in external style sheet vs inline?

[image]

Comment: If you want to show the image you'll need to change the property to `display: inline;` or `display: block;` instead of declaring it blank.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But, could you please help me understand how you knew that. And would you move your comment to answer section so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a image hidden by `display: none;`, it is necessary to revert the display property back to its original display property.

```
display: block;  /* use if you made the image if it floated or acts like a <div> */
display: inline; /* default image display type (USE THIS ONE) */
```

I noticed that in your code:

```
targetid.Style.Add("display", "");
```

You were trying to show an image by declaring the display property 'blank'. This does not work because `display: NULL` is not a CSS property and causes the browser to ignore its value and revert back to using `display: none;`. The image stays hidden and your intended behavior is not applied.

## Further Discussion

while I hope my solution helps fix the problem, I do have a solution:

Instead of using a "display: none;" to hide an element and then unhiding it by reverting the value back to its original property do this:

Add a class called ".hidden:

```
.hidden { display: none;}
```

Whenever you want to make an element disapper simply add the class ".hidden" to the element. When you want to show the element again, simply remove the class.

The advantage is two fold:

- Removes the requirement of reverting back to the original value and having to distinguish between display: inline, block, inline-block, etc.
- Standardizes the hide component accross your entire web application.

regards and good luck.